# AWS Lambda Ends Before Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda which will ultimately be triggered by an API Gateway request, but when I deploy it and test it in the console,
it stops before showing any sign if things running. I increased the timeout and the memory from 128MB to 512MB, and it still stopped.
Please see small code snippet below. Lambda never reaches any of the **@@BP8.x** lines. They are inside an if, but the if does not
do anything time intensive. What should I look for to figure out why it stopped?

General Configuration:
Memory: 512 MB
Ephemeral storage: 512MB
Timeout 0 min 10 sec

My Lambda log stream shows:

```
2022-11-07T21:51:17.622-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.622Z undefined INFO @@BP10
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.622-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.622Z undefined INFO @@BP11
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.626-05:00   START RequestId: b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e Version: $LATEST
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.627-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.627Z b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e INFO @@BP7
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.627-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.627Z b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e INFO @@BP7 event= {"type":"VEHICLE_REPAIR","urn":"urn:mycomp:xqa:vehicle:fleetVehicle:202211072142","vin":"<received VIN>","class":"<received vehicle class>","status":"REPAIR","owningLocation":"urn:mycomp:xqa:location:branch<generated id>","spanId":"<received span Id>","traceId":"<generated trace Id>"}
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.627-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.627Z b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e INFO @@BP7 context= {"callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop":true,"functionVersion":"$LATEST","functionName":"VehicleService","memoryLimitInMB":"512","logGroupName":"/aws/lambda/VehicleService","logStreamName":"2022/11/08/[$LATEST]bcf91d836e4a41da92996935f3e0a306","invokedFunctionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:998414783091:function:VehicleService","awsRequestId":"b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e"}
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.627-05:00   2022-11-08T02:51:17.627Z b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e INFO EVENT { "type": "VEHICLE_REPAIR", "urn": "urn:mycomp:xqa:vehicle:fleetVehicle:202211072142", "vin": "<received VIN>", "class": "<received vehicle class>", "status": "REPAIR", "owningLocation": "urn:mycomp:xqa:location:branch<generated id>", "spanId": "<received span Id>", "traceId": "<generated trace Id>" }
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.750-05:00   END RequestId: b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e
    2022-11-07T21:51:17.750-05:00   REPORT RequestId: b5697c1a-aac2-4676-b349-3a315fede92e Duration: 122.30 ms Billed Duration: 123 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 139 MB Init Duration: 788.40 ms
```

This  is an abbreviated form of my index.js for my Lambda. The real code does have much more, but I'm trying to ask questions not related to the rest of it.

```
console.info('@@BP10');
function someFunction() { }).promise(); }
console.info('@@BP11');


// Main function
exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    console.info('@@BP7');
    console.info('@@BP7 event=', JSON.stringify(event));
    console.info('@@BP7 context=', JSON.stringify(context));
    if (event.requestContext != null) {
        console.info('@@BP8.1 does not run');
        doSomeThings();
        } else {
            console.info("@@BP8.2 does not run");
        }
        console.info("@@BP8.3 does not run");
    else {
        console.info("@@BP8.4 does not run");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `async` handler, the Lambda function probably finishes before the handler finishes its execution. To rectify that you can wrap your code in a **promise** as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think you may be onto something. Even a code block like if (event.requestContext != null) {} would return before it gets executed or even attempted? Why would it even bother to print out the @@BP7 lines? Also, a lot of the code inside this calls other code that returns a promise, though I call await before it. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @Woodsman Try and see with the Promise wrapper if that changes anything.

Comment: My Lambda is an async function calling an async function, and sometimes that also calls an async function. That's 3 levels of promises. Should the Lambda resolve to return a Promise to return the innermost result, or would it be better to have a Promise to return the second most inner result?